# Selenium looking at a class and determine how many elements are in the class, finally executes an action on all elements found

Tags: python, selenium, web, dynamic

I need to interact with elements under a class but the number of elements in that class is changing every time I run the script.

To give you context the website is a calendar, where I need to pick a day that I'll use as a template for my work. Every time I run the script (Monthly) the webpage with the calendar is updated to show the current month, thus Selenium picks the same day it did in the previous month. But every month the day Selenium picks has different contents and number of elements change every month. Currently, for example, the script is written to interact with 5 elements, but for next month it won't work because the day picked will have a different number of elements. So every month I have to manually change the script to interact with the correct number of elements.

Here's an example of the element structure of the website:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled tags-list grid_9">
     <li><!-- react-text: 185 -->Text<!-- /react-text --><i data-id="0" class="icon-cancel pointer icon12 
      ml5px error"></i></li>
     <li><!-- react-text: 188 -->Text<!-- /react-text --><i data-id="1" class="icon-cancel pointer icon12 
      ml5px error"></i></li>
     <li><!-- react-text: 191 -->Text<!-- /react-text --><i data-id="2" class="icon-cancel pointer icon12 
      ml5px error"></i></li>
</ul>
```

So the number of elements that I need to interact within the class 'list-unstyled tags-list grid_9' is always changing. The elements with the id's "0", "1" and "2". Sometimes there might be 4 elements with ID's "0", "1", "2", "3" and sometimes there's 2 elements etc.

I've been trying to figure out how to write a script where Selenium looks inside that class ''list-unstyled tags-list grid_9', see's how many elements are in there and executes a -

```
driver.find_element_by_(xpath,class,id whatever).click()
```

on all of the elements found in there.

UPDATE:
So I tried this code:

```
tab = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#postForm > div:nth-child(3) > ul.list-unstyled.tags-list.grid_9')
    hashs = tab.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')
    for element in hashs:
        element.find_element_by_tag_name('i').click()
```

And it gave me this error:

```
stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Comment: use `find_elements_by_xxx` with **s** in word **elements** to get list with all elements. And then you can use `len()` to see how many elements on list or use `for`-loop to work with all elements.

Comment: Once I use find_elements_xxx where are they stored and how do I interact with them?

Comment: you get list `list_with_elements = find_elements_by_xxx(...)` and you can use `for`-loop to work with every element separatelly `for item in list_with_elements: item.click()`

Comment: I did ```list_hash = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('icon-cancel pointer icon12 ml5px error')
    for element in list_hash: element.click()``` and here is the element structure for one of the elements: ```<li>
<!-- react-text: 185 -->TEXT<!-- /react-text -->
<i data-id="0" class="icon-cancel pointer icon12 ml5px error"></i></li>```

But it didn't click and just moved on with the script executing everything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are very close to acheive your objective. Just try to click with JS.

```
tab = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#postForm > div:nth-child(3) > ul.list-unstyled.tags-list.grid_9')
hashs = tab.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')
for element in hashs:
    x_element=element.find_element_by_tag_name('i')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", x_element)
```

**OR**

Wait for element to be clickable and then click.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

tab = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#postForm > div:nth-child(3) > ul.list-unstyled.tags-list.grid_9')
hashs = tab.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')

number_of_buttons = len(hashs)
for x in range(number_of_buttons):

   button = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#postForm > div:nth-child(3) > ul.list-unstyled.tags-list.grid_9 > li:nth-child(" + str(x+1) + ") > i")))
    button.click()
```

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please explain what does len command does exactly? Sorry for a newbie question....

Comment: Len is return length or num of Li for iteration and creating webelement in for loop to prevent element to become stale in next iteration.

Comment: yes and the first solution did not work, still gave me a stale element error. But the second one worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: @plx23 Second is recommended also as we are using webdriver wait as standard practice. Please accept it as answer to help SO community

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that an element also has all the `find_elem...` methods that the webdriver has, but with the context of that element  only, that works for you in the following way:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
calendar_day_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('ul.list-unstyled.tags-list.grid_9')
day_events = calendar_day_element.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')
```

Now `day_events` is a list of all `li` elements inside the selected day and you can iterate over it.

Edit:
Given your needs to click the `<i>` element I changed the last line to:

```
day_events = calendar_day_element.find_elements_by_css_selector('li > i')
```

The `li > i` selector means give me all `<i>` elements that are direct child of a `<li>` element

Comment: This is on the right track, but I need to interact with an element inside of the 'li', specifically with ```<i data-id="1" class="icon-cancel pointer icon12 
      ml5px error"></i>```

Comment: ```calendar_day_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('ul.list-unstyled.tags-list.grid_9')
day_events = calendar_day_element.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')
for element in day_events:
element.click()```

^ won't work because it clicks on the whole tab, instead of the small element thats an 'x' which I mentioned before (<i data-id="1" class="icon-cancel pointer icon12 
      ml5px error"></i>)

Answer (score 0):

Stale Element Reference Exception occurs if a page refreshes or an element changes on the page (also refreshes or disappears). In your case, this is likely happening either with `tab`, `hash` or 2nd `element` (cannot say without seeing the page).

To avoid Stale Element Reference Exception, try re-locating elements before interacting with them, something like:

```
tab = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#postForm > div:nth-child(3) > ul.list-unstyled.tags-list.grid_9')
hashs = tab.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')

for i in range(len(hashs)):
    tab = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#postForm > div:nth-child(3) > ul.list-unstyled.tags-list.grid_9')
    element = tab.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')[i]
    element.find_element_by_tag_name('i').click()
```

Hopefully, this helps. Good luck!

Comment: How could I distinguish between each of the 3 reasons (tab, hash and 2nd element) why an element goes stale? And what would be the solution for each? If you don't mind elaborating and have the time/energy lol Thank you!

Comment: Sure. You usually should be able to distinguish visually, just look for an element that refreshes or disappears/reappears on the page. 
If cannot see any visual behavior like that, you can use my code and try to exclude re-finds 1 by one. 

For example, see in the for loop, I search for tab again? tab = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#postForm > div:nth-child(3) > ul.list-unstyled.tags-list.grid_9')

Take that line out, run the script - if everything works without this line, in means tab doesn't go stale.